# Child process variable doesn't die with process?

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am spawning a process using `child_process`'s `.spawn` like this:

```
prc = spawn('java',  ['-jar', '-Xmx512M', 'jarfile.jar']);
```

Which works just fine, however when the process ends, the `prc` variable is still alive with all the data, for example:

```
# console.log(prc.pid);
# 32407
```

But if I try to check if that pid exists in my linux system:

```
# kill -0 32407
# bash: kill: (32407) - No such process
```

Is this simply the behaviour of `child_process.spawn`?
Are there any workarounds?